# Summing two elements of two UITextFields

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, xcode4.5, ibaction

I'm having an issue with summing the element of one UITextField with the element of another UITextField and having the answer displayed in a third UITextField (called answer). The summation would happen by pressing a button. Here's the code I have for the IBAction:

-(IBAction) {

```
 answer.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",([text1.text intValue] + [text2.text intValue])]];
```

}

All I get is an error message saying "Expected Identifier"

Comment: "-(IBAction)" is not a correct message declaration.

Comment: Why is this not a correct message declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message needs a name, and you have too many brackets. Try this:

```
-(IBAction)myAction {
  answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",([text1.text intValue] + [text2.text intValue])];
}
```

Comment: WOW dumb of me, I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was happening...just careless. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you could upvote my answers, this would be nice :)